# Display Laravel artisan command output (command called from another command)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am writing a console command. This command also calls another command.

Basically say: `php artisan command:one`. So inside command one, I call `php artisan command:two`.

They both have interactions (`$this->info()`) stating the progress or state of the current operations. But when I run `php artisan command:one` I can't see this displayed info from `php artisan command:two`, though `php artisan command:two` has its own output info and progress state.

How do I ensure to see the progress and states from `php artisan command:two` which is called in `php artisan command:one`?

Comment: How exactly do you call `command:two`? Show the code, please.

Comment: You may want to refer to exactly the documentation on this matter: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands

Comment: @Styx `Artisan::call('command:two')`

Comment: @D.Petrov trying that: seems promising though: thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `Artisan::call()` doesn't redirect called command's output to original command's output.

To call another Artisan command and save its output you should use `$this->call()` from your command.

Comment: could you share how we can save `$this->call()`'s output?